# Push notification when new video is uploaded on Youtube channel

Tags: android, api, youtube, push-notification

I was looking for a way to get a push notification whenever a new video is updated on a specific channel.
Basically, this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlZZghBnfdM
but I can't find this Youtube push API. Is it already available?

Is there a known way to achieve something similar on Android?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I was looking for almost same thing.